# Highlight unused variables in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible somehow set eclipse to highlight unused variables or methods in Java project? It will bring much overhead for Eclipse?

Comment: There is a Problems view which should already show warnings where unused variables are included. I suggest using inspection tools like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) or [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) to check for those errors (and many more).

Comment: Eclipse does that out of the box. Which exact variables are you talking about?

Comment: public class Statistic
{public static int saleRequests = 0;} saleRequests is unused in my project

Comment: It is `public` it might be used in other places.

Comment: I expert that Eclipse will check other places like References does

Comment: Define other places.

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

- Window
- Preferences
- Java
- Compiler
- Errors/Warnings (also available "per project")
- Scroll down to "Unnecessary code"

Eclipse can, however, only inspect certain elements. It is hard to tell for eclipse, if a *public method in a public class* is referenced in other code at runtime. This depends on which code uses your code.

For even better code analysis use a plugin of a code metric tool (like *PMD* or similar).

Comment: I don't want to have this info in compile time. I would like to see marked unused variables in editor. Something like unused imports

Comment: This also works great for highlighting unused parameters